# PHP - Recover real-time data from a remote server

Tags: php, symfony, unix

I have a website in Symfony 3, which runs a script on a remote server UNIX.
I would like to know the progress(steps) of the script in real time or every X seconds, on the website without the user needing to reload the page.

What solution should be considered?

---

**Edit** - About the script:

When a user clicks a button, Symfony run a shell script that is present on the same server as my web application. The shell script connects to SSH on a remote server (user) and installs components on the remote server.
The shell script is quite long and complex.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible solutions:

You can do an interval that checks every x milliseconds for any changes and will apply those changes to your front-end.

The other option is to set up using web sockets and would recommend this over interval checking. It maintains an active connection to the server so it is near instant if not instant.

I would suggest checking out this bundle: https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle

Comment: Thx, I edited my post in order to speak more precisely, of the role that the script has. Do you think it's still possible with WebSocket?

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually understand how

> which runs a script on a remote server UNIX

you are doing this but this is the solution you can use.

1. Have a symfony command that listens on remote service/server/app etc.
2. Have a symfony controller that streams the response from the console commands and echos the result in twig template as they arrive.

With this way, users don't need to refresh the pages. Wheel has already been invented here [Streaming console command output from symfony controller](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/stkb/streaming-console-command-output-from-symfony-controller) for you. You just need to update the command as per your requirements.

Note: If you don't want console command approach, this is commandless version. [Streaming symfony response from twig template with XMLHttpRequest](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/canq/streaming-symfony-response-from-twig-template-with-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: Thx, I edited my post in order to speak more precisely, of the role that the script has. With your solution, just send the returns of the shell script in XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Yes, both examples do what you need. Just create a simple command and test them. They work fine.

Comment: I tested it and I think it does not fit. If the user wants to change the page during the AJAX call, it is impossible to know where the script has arrived after.